# Package install error "We couldn't validate Custom Action"

Tags: change-set, unmanaged-package

I have this unmanaged package with a custom quick action (in a custom object) calling a flow. All details are part of the package (uploads correctly), but when installing in a fresh org, I got this error:

Component [force:highlightsPanel] attribute [actionNames] We couldn't validate Custom Action

The package contains all components (object/fields, flexipage, quick action, flow), and I can't find the solution.

Has anyone faced this issue and found a way to solve?

Thanks!

Comment: Possibly related: https://issues.salesforce.com/issue/a028c00000gAyqtAAC/metadata-doesnt-handle-namespace-for-installed-custombutton

Comment: Oops: "There isn't a workaround for this issue yet." Oh my... there go my custom actions.

Comment: `Solution Deployed` status implies they fixed it: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000386216&type=1 . Open a support case.